# If the current browser url contains a word, do something

Tags: java, android, webview

If my Webview (mainWebView) **current** URL contains a word like "/start", I want let it do something. Currently throwing out errors, some ideas?

```
public class GatewayActivity extends Activity {
private String CurUrl;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gateway);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView1);

        // other Webview Data

        mainWebView.loadUrl("https://url.com/start");
            CurUrl = mainWebView.getOriginalUrl();

        if(CurUrl.indexOf("/start") > -1) {
            Toast error=Toast.makeText(this,  "test",  2000);   
            error.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast error=Toast.makeText(this,  "test failed",  2000);    
            error.show();
        }

}
```

Edit:
Thanks for help, but still getting error like that one:

```
    08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.XXX.XXX/com.XXX.XXX.GatewayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at com.XXX.XXX.GatewayActivity.onCreate(GatewayActivity.java:72)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
08-01 17:42:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(16741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
```

But only with included my If-query like above.

---

Still not work.

Same error, changed to:

```
mainWebView.loadUrl("https://url.com");

        String cururl = null;
        cururl = mainWebView.getOriginalUrl();


        if(cururl.contains("/start")) {
            //Toast error=Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
            //error.show();
        }
        else {
            //Toast error2=Toast.makeText(this,  "nope",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
            //error2.show();
        }
```

Comment: What errors is it throwing? Can you edit and paste a stack trace?

Comment: Also, `if(CurUrl.indexOf("/start") > -1)` is pretty clumsy.  Try using `if(CurUrl.contains("/start"))` instead.  If you want to make it case-insensitve you could do `if(CurUrl.toLowerCase().contains(<some-all-lower-case-string))` as well

Comment: Oh, one other thing - Variables in Java, by convention, should start with a lowercase letter, and then be camel-case. ie, `curUrl` rather than `CurUrl`.  The only exception to that is constants, in which case they should be `ALL_UPPER_CASE`

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work.. posted my error log!

Comment: Which statement is line 72? A null pointer exception means that something on that line hasn't been initialized.  I'd do a `System.out.println()`for each object referenced on that line.  One of them is null.  When you figure out which one, initialize it prior to the call on line 72 and your problem will go away.

Answer (score 2):

One mistake I see in your code is in the syntax of `Toast.makeTest(this,  "test",  2000)`

You have specified the duration to `2000` which is wrong. The only values supported by Toast duration are `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`, whose values in integer are 0 and 1.

Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

What if You try to parse "/start" in onPageFinished (or even onPageStarted)

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { 
 super.onPageFinished(view, url);
 if(url.contains("/start")) {
            Toast.makeText(GatewayActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(GatewayActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

if You'll get the same error, so your problem in other stuff.